# ResponsiveSlides.js not working in https protocol

Tags: joomla, responsive-slides

when the site is opened vie https:// the slide is not showing. Even to change the location of the files with full path.
I mean `https://www.example.com/images/......` it is not showing anything.
but in `http://www.example.com/images/......` it is working.

Can someone help with this.
the site is joomla template.

Regards.

Comment: If you are Joomla user/developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.